# Xcode cannot find referenced Storyboard using Cocoapods

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, cocoapods, uistoryboard

I'm trying to create a Pod using CocoaPods and I want to bundle a "Demo" Storyboard that I can reference to from the Main Storyboard from my example application. The problem is that Xcode gives me the following compiler error when I do so:

`Did not find storyboard named "Demo" referenced from Main.storyboard`

See:

[image]

[image]

In my Podspec, I included:

```
s.resource_bundles = {
    'StoryboardAssets' => ['Pod/Assets/*.{storyboard,png}']
}
```

You can find the demo repository that I created using the "[Using Pod Lib Create](https://guides.cocoapods.org/making/using-pod-lib-create.html)" guide, you can find it here:

https://github.com/Kukiwon/StoryboardDemo

I'm running CocoaPods version 0.39.0.

So what would be the proper way to reference a Storyboard from your Pod? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 6):

**To reference storyboard using cocoapods, you should set in the Bundle section, the bundle identifier of the pod, like the picture below:**

[image]

And in your podspec file, you should add the reference of your storyboard (as resource and not bundle)

**`s.resource = 'MyPod/MyStoryboardName.storyboard'`**

After the pod update, everything will work as expected

Hope that helps

Comment: This worked for me! For some reason having the storyboard under s.resource_bundles wasn't good enough. But after I added the s.resource it worked!

Answer (score 4):

Files included in a Dynamic Framework are embedded in a different `NSBundle` in the application. To make it easier to obtain the storyboard, you can create a helper class **inside** your library:

```
public class StoryboardHelper: NSObject {
    public static let helper = StoryboardHelper()

    public lazy var storyboard: UIStoryboard! = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: NSBundle(forClass: StoryboardHelper.self))

    public func rootController() -> UIViewController! {
        return storyboard.instantiateInitialViewController()
    }
}
```

`NSBundle(forClass: StoryboardHelper.self)` will obtain the bundle of `StoryboardHelper`.

This way, your user only needs to do the following to show your root view controller of the embedded storyboard:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

    window?.rootViewController = StoryboardHelper.helper.rootController()
    window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

    return true
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but looking at the demo application on GitHub, how would this apply to my project? In your example, you instantiate the "Main" storyboard inside the Pod, but I want to reference the "Demo" storyboard from my "Main" Storyboard. Also, I was wondering if this can be done only using Storyboards (with Storyboard references in iOS9). Do you think it's possible?