# Where storyboards should be included in a pod project?

Tags: ios, cocoapods

I'm trying to generated a  `Pod` with some graphics into a storyboard.
Well, my issue is the next.

When I try to run

`pod spec lint --verbose`

I get the next error:

> The following build commands failed:
>       ComipileStoryboard MyProject/Example/Base.lproj/Main.storyboard
>       - ERRRO | [iOS] xcodebuild: Returned an unsuccessful exit code.

Where I should add the `storyboards` files?

Comment: Can you post your `podspec` ?. It  should be inside resources

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anything other than source files will go in `resources` or `resource-bundles`

```
Pod::Spec.new do |spec|
  spec.name         = 'YOUR_LIB_NAME'
  spec.version      = '1.0' 
  spec.source_files = 'YOUR_LIB_NAME/*'
  spec.resource_bundles = {
    'YOUR_LIB_NAME' => ['YOUR_LIB_NAME/YOUR_PATH_TO_STORYBOARD/*.storyboard']
  }

end
```

Comment: Awesome, now it compiles!!! But, now, how I can import this storyboard view in antoher project?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35501599/xcode-cannot-find-referenced-storyboard-using-cocoapods The important part is "Bundle".